# Showing the same image repeatedly in a DataGridView without memory over-use

Tags: vb.net, datagridviewimagecolumn

I think I'm doing something very stupid, but can't find an alternative!

I've got a list of files that my form is going to process, and am using a datagridview to show them all and my progress through the list. I've got a "waiting" "processing" and "done" image resource, and throw them all into a `DataGridViewImageColumn`.

```
For Each file As String In folderListing
     DataGridView1.Rows.Add(file, My.Resources.WaitingImg)

Next
```

Problem is, it seems to use a little tiny chunk of RAM for each of those images, and when I have 5,000 of them in a test run it used 4Gb...

How do I do this so it's only loading the resource once but displaying it in hundreds or thousands of places?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use any property of `My.Resources` repeatedly. Every time you use such a property, it extracts the data from the resource and creates a new object. In any particular context, get the property once, assign to a variable and then use that variable multiple times, e.g.

```vb
Dim waitingImg = My.Resources.WaitingImg

For Each file As String In folderListing
     DataGridView1.Rows.Add(file, waitingImg)
Next
```

If you need to change the images, assign the resource properties to fields first and then use those fields to set the cell values as and when required.

Comment: Thanks, that's probably why I couldn't find any answer either - it was a completely different error than I'd anticipated!